# Doob-Meyer decomposition with respect to different filtrations

Tags: stochastic-processes, point-processes

It is known that the Doob-Meyer theorem gives us a unique decomposition,

$N(t)=A(t)+M(t)$

and the compensator part may conditional on a filtration $F_1$: $A(t|F_1)$.

My question is: Does the Doob-Meyer decomposition still exist if we conditional on a different filtration $F_2$? For the moment, I only care about a specific filtration: $F_2 \subset F_1$.

And if so, any example?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "different filtration"? As long as you can apply the Doob-Meyer theorem, you will obviously get a decomposiiton for the given filtration.

Comment: @skyindeer : For explicit augmentation of filtration and under some hypotheses, you have explicit decomposition of the Martingale and non Martingale part of the decomposition in the big filtration using the smaller filtration decomposition. Look for example at chapter six of Protter's book on stochastic integration (there is also a Lecture Note Mathematics by Yor and Mansuy that has at least a chapter on this)

Comment: @TheBridge Thanks a lot for the infor, I will look into it.